# Why are all my parent functions returning null even though there is a parent?

Tags: javascript, html

NOTE: this is for homework, please only answer in a way that honors academic integrity.

Whenever I call a parent node, it returns null, even though it has a parent, and  I know that is what it is supposed to do if there is no parent. the program is supposed to display the hierarchy of the DOM from parent to child.

### JavaScript

```
            var styleChange = "";
            function start() {
                window.addEventListener("mousedown", changeStyleTo, false);
            }

            window.addEventListener("load", start, false);

            function changeStyleTo(e) {
                e.target.setAttribute("style", "background-color: yellow; color: red");
                window.addEventListener("mouseup", changeStyleBack, false);
            }

            function changeStyleBack(e) {
                var current = e.target.cloneNode();
                window.alert(current.nodeName);

                var elementString = current.nodeName;

                for (var i = 0; i < document.body.childElementCount; i++) {
                    if (current != document.body) {
                        elementString += current.tagName;
                        current = current.parentNode;
                    }
                }
                window.alert("elementString");

                e.target.setAttribute("style", "background-color: white; color: black");
            }
```

### HTML

```
    <body id="Body">
        <h1 id="H1">The 23<sup>rd</sup> Psalm</h1>
        <h2 id="H2">A Psalm of David.</h2>
        <ol id="Ol"> 
            <li id="Li1">
                The LORD is my shepherd; I shall not want.
            </li>
            <li id="li2">
                He maketh me to lie down in green pastures: he leadeth me beside the still waters.
            </li>
            <li id="li3">
                He restoreth my soul: he leadeth me in the paths of righteousness for his name's sake.
            </li>
            <li id="li4">
                Yea, though I walk through the valley of the shadow of death, I will fear no evil: for thou art with me; thy rod and thy staff they comfort me.
            </li>
            <li id="li5">
                Thou preparest a table before me in the presence of mine enemies: thou anointest my head with oil; my cup runneth over.
            </li>
            <li id="li6">
                Surely goodness and mercy shall follow me all the days of my life: and I will dwell in the house of the LORD for ever.
            </li>
        </ol>
        <hr id="Hr"/>
        <p id="p1">
            <del id="Del">
                &copy; 1611, THE MOST HIGH AND MIGHTY PRINCE JAMES, BY THE GRACE OF GOD KING OF GREAT BRITAIN, FRANCE, AND IRELAND, DEFENDER OF THE FAITH, etc.  <strong>All rights reserved.</strong>
            </del>
        </p>
        <p id="p2">
            <ins id="Ins">
                This text is in the <strong>Public Domain</strong>.
            </ins>
        </p>
        <p id="p3">
            Return to
            <a id="A" href="http://www.masters.edu" title="The Master's College Home Page">
                The Master's College
                <img src="masters.png" width="125" height="180" alt="The Master's College logo"/>
            </a>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: My guess is that "var current = e.target.cloneNode();" messes things up. Are you certain that the reference to the parent is actually copied? And why would you want to do this anyway?!

Comment: What “parent functions” do you mean? `.parentNode` is a property, not a function. You don’t call it, you read it.

Comment: There are a few things to improve in this post. First up, the initial disclaimer is not needed: we help beginners and advanced users alike as long as the posts follow the guidelines from the help center. Second, there's a lot of code going on there, probably way more than needed to demonstrate the issue. See "[mcve]" for guidance. Finally, it's unclear (to me) what the specific problem is. You could try adding your attempted solutions and explain why they didn't work, or elaborate in other ways.

Comment: to be honest I'm not sure how to elaborate further. and also I think, but I may be wrong, the disclaimer is needed because I believe it is technically illegal to directly post homework, so for legal reasons I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
var current = e.target.cloneNode();
```

write this:

```
var current = e.target;
```

Also your loop is not optimized, remove the loop and modify your `if` condition to be a `while` loop instead.

Comment: Thanks so much. Literally perfect, you're the best. :)